# Dynamically create value labels with haven::labelled

Tags: r, spss, r-haven

I am using haven::labelled to set value labels of a variable. The goal is to create a fully documented dataset I can export to SPSS.

Now, say I have a df `value_labels` of values and their value labels. I also have i df `df_data` with variables to which I want allocate value labels.

```
value_labels <- tibble(
  value = 1:6,
  labels = paste0("value", 1:6)
)

df_data <- tibble(
  id = 1:10, 
  var = floor(runif(10, 1, 6))
)
```

Manually, I would create value labels for `df_data$var` like so:

```
df_data$var <- haven::labelled(df_data$var, labels = c(values1 = 1, values2 =  2, values3 = 3, values4 = 4, values5 = 5, values6 = 6))
```

But since I have more than 16 datasets with close to 7 000 columns I need a more dynamic way of assigning value labels. Note that there is, as i understand it, difference between `"values1" = 1` and `values1 = 1` (quotations marks), depending on the variable class.

Note that I use `haven::labelled` since it is the only way, so far, I have been able to successfully export a .sav-file with value labels. I have tried `sjlabelled`, but with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `deframe` the 'value_labels', use that as `labels` argument in the `labelled` function

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
df_data %>%
     mutate(var = haven::labelled(var, labels = deframe(value_labels[2:1])))
```

If there are more columns, then use `mutate_at`

```
df_data %>%
     mutate_at(vars(var), ~ haven::labelled(., labels = deframe(value_labels[2:1])))
```

---

With multiple datasets, place them in a `list` and use `map` to loop over the `list` and apply at once

```
library(purrr)
keyval <- deframe(value_labels[2:1])
list(df_data, df_data) %>%
    map( ~
          .x %>%
             mutate_at(vars(var), ~ haven::labelled(., labels = 
             keyval)))
```

Comment: Now say that I extend the df `value_labels`, so that it contains the value labels of `var1` and `var2`.


`value_labels <- tibble(value = c(seq(1:6), seq(1:3)), labels = c(paste0("value", 1:6),paste0("value", 1:3)), name = c(rep("var1", 6), rep("var2", 3))))`

`df_data <- tibble(id = 1:10, var1 = floor(runif(10, 1, 7)), var2 = floor(runif(10, 1, 4)))`

How would you assign the correct value labels to the correct variable in `df_data`?

Comment: @oskjerv  Can you please post as a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59376487/dynamically-create-value-labels-with-havenlabelled-follow-up