# Dynamically create value labels with haven::labelled, follow-up

Tags: r, r-haven

Follow-up question to [Dynamically create value labels with haven::labelled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59360232/7513118), where [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun) provided a good answer using `deframe`.

I am using haven::labelled to set value labels of a variable. The goal is to create a fully documented dataset I can export to SPSS.

Now, say I have a df `value_labels` of values and their value labels. I also have a df `df_data` with variables to which I want allocate value labels.

```
value_labels <- tibble(
  value = c(seq(1:6), seq(1:3), NA),
  labels = c(paste0("value", 1:6),paste0("value", 1:3), NA),
  name = c(rep("var1", 6), rep("var2", 3), "var3")
)


df_data <- tibble(
  id = 1:10, 
  var1 = floor(runif(10, 1, 7)),
  var2 = floor(runif(10, 1, 4)), 
  var3 = rep("string", 10)
)
```

Manually, I would create value labels for `df_data$var1` and `df_data$var2` like so:

```
df_data$var1 <- haven::labelled(df_data$var, labels = c(values1 = 1, values2 =  2, values3 = 3, values4 = 4, values5 = 5, values6 = 6))

df_data$var2 <- haven::labelled(df_data$var, labels = c(values1 = 1, values2 =  2, values3 = 3))
```

I need a more dynamic way of assigning correct value labels to the correct variable in a large dataset. The solution also needs to ignore `character` vectors, since I dont want these to have value labels. For that reason, `var3` in `value_labels` is listed as `NA`.

The solution **does not** need to work with multiple datasets in a list.

Comment: The datasets Im working with have character vectors. In this example `df_data$var3`. These character vectors contains long strings (comments). Logically, these can`t have value labels. But it is important to keep the character vectors in the final dataset. Let me know if I can clarify any further.

Comment: Can you check the solution posted below

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option where we `split` the named 'value/labels' by 'name' after removing the `NA` rows, use the names of the `list` to subset the columns of 'df_data', apply the `labelled` and assign it to back to the same columns

```
lbls2 <- na.omit(value_labels)
lstLbls <- with(lbls2, split(setNames(value, labels), name))
df_data[names(lstLbls)] <- Map(haven::labelled, 
          df_data[names(lstLbls)], labels = lstLbls)
df_data
# A tibble: 10 x 4
#      id       var1       var2 var3  
#   <int>  <dbl+lbl>  <dbl+lbl> <chr> 
# 1     1 2 [value2] 2 [value2] string
# 2     2 5 [value5] 2 [value2] string
# 3     3 4 [value4] 1 [value1] string
# 4     4 1 [value1] 2 [value2] string
# 5     5 1 [value1] 1 [value1] string
# 6     6 6 [value6] 2 [value2] string
# 7     7 1 [value1] 3 [value3] string
# 8     8 1 [value1] 1 [value1] string
# 9     9 3 [value3] 3 [value3] string
#10    10 6 [value6] 1 [value1] string
```